# Collections.rotate() as copy of the arraylist in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

```
    ArrayList<Integer> obj = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5));
    Collections.rotate(obj,+1);
    Collections.rotate(obj,+2);
```

If i rotate arrayList using collections it rotate original array.
I need to rotate a particular index and save it in next index/desired index without affecting the original index?

Like below, all in same array

```
input:  
1
2
3
4
5
output: 
1  5  4
2  1  5
3  2  1
4  3  2
5  4  3
```

Now im doing like this, as below

```
ArrayList<Integer> arraySec = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Integer> arrayThrd = new ArrayList<Integer>();
arraySec.addAll(obj);
Collections.rotate(arraySec,+1);
arrayThrd.addAll(arraySec);
Collections.rotate(arrayThrd,+1);
```

because of this i need so many arrays for each index that goes more than 5 arrays. Any other way to rotate and return as copy of it instead of original  one

Comment: You want to print all rotations of the input (not just 3) vertically, right?

Comment: You could consider using a custom data structure which, though backed by one array, has multiple rotated representations. This is maybe feasible if you only care about, for example, the Iterable interface. I can post more as an answer, but curious about particular issue to be resolved: Algorithm speed? Memory footprint reduction? Memory allocation reduction? And what can you afford to give up for gains?

Answer (score 0):

If the `Collections.rotate` method doesn't return a new copy of the original list, just write one yourself!

```
static <T> ArrayList<T> rotate(ArrayList<T> list, int distance) {
    ArrayList<T> newList = new ArrayList<>(list);
    Collections.rotate(newList, distance);
    return newList;
}
```

You can use it like this to print the desired output:

```
    ArrayList<Integer> obj = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(3,6,4,1,9));
    List<ArrayList<Integer>> listOfArrayLists =
            IntStream.range(0, obj.size()) // replace obj.size() with however many rotations you want
            .mapToObj(x -> rotate(obj, x))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
    for (int i = 0 ; i < listOfArrayLists.get(0).size() ; i++) {
        for (ArrayList<Integer> listOfArrayList : listOfArrayLists) {
            System.out.print(listOfArrayList.get(i));
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

If you actually want to print *all* the rotations of the array list in this "transposed" way, then you don't actually need this many new array lists! If you haven't noticed already, the first line of the output is the same as the input array list reversed and rotated by 1. The second line is the input reversed and rotated by 2, and so on. Therefore, this will produce exactly the same result:

```
    Collections.reverse(obj);
    for (int i = 0 ; i < obj.size() ; i++) {
        Collections.rotate(obj, 1);
        for (Integer j : obj) {
            System.out.print(j);
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```